# Dismissible Height not matching child height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter, but I really enjoy the language and hope to find some answers to my probably very dumb issue :)

I have a ToDo List App and it contains a ListView with dismissible tiles.
I added a divier to seperate tiles, but after adding a dividor the height of the Dismissible does not match its child anymore.

As you can see without dividors the dismissible height matches the one of its child:

[image]

As you can see with the dividors the dismissible height does not match the one of its child. Or atleast that is what I think (keep in mind my non exisiting knowledge of this language). The dismissible height seems greater than the one of the child.

[image]

This is how I build the dismissibles:

```
return Dismissible(
          key: Key(item.getId()),
          direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
          background: Container(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0),
              child: Icon(
                Icons.delete,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            toDoRemove(index);
          },
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              leading: Theme(
                  data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white24),
                  child: Checkbox(
                      checkColor: Colors.white,
                      activeColor: Colors.blue,
                      value: item.isDone(),
                      onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                        toDoToggle(index, newValue);
                      })),
              title: Text(item.getTitle()),
            ),
            Divider(
              color: Colors.white24,
              thickness: 0.0,
            ),
          ]));
```

As can be seen in the code the child of the Dismissible is a Column which contains two children:

- List Tile
- Divider

I would appreciate any Help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I messed up. Instead of wrapping the divider inside the dismissible it would be smarter to have the divider in a column with the dismissible. This way the divider is not contained in the dismissible anymore.

Updated Code:

```
 return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch, children: <Widget>[
        Dismissible(
          ...
          child: // No Column anymore
            ListTile(
              leading: Theme(
                  data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white24),
                  child: Checkbox(
                      checkColor: Colors.white,
                      activeColor: Colors.blue,
                      value: item.isDone(),
                      onChanged: (bool newValue) {
                        toDoToggle(index, newValue);
                      })),
              title: Text(item.getTitle()),
            ),
          ),
        Container(decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.white24, width: 0.4))))
      ]);
```

And also appearently Dividers always have some paddings thus I used a Container with decoration to mimic a divider.

Here is the result:

[image]

And now it works as expected.